# Redux-form Why external input stop working?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

https://codesandbox.io/s/form-redux-6lvvo?file=/src/components/ContactForm.js:8134-8139

This is my sandbox where i try new stuff before use them in the main program.
But i have a problem with redux-form.
As you can see in the demo there is an external input "test", if you try to write in it u can see that stop works at the first character and then it just start to work as is supposed to.
With native input i have no problem at all.

I fixed it writing the event return inside the ContactForm return like that:

```html
let ContactForm = (props) => {
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log("ciao");
  };

  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState("panel1");

  //handler
  const handleChange = (panel) => (event, isExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    props.initialize({
      oggetto: "ciao",
      inizio: "ciao",
      data: "ciao",
      fine: "ciao",
      luogo: "ciao",
      note: "ciao",
      preavviso: "ciao",
      tipologia: "ciao",
      stato: "ciao",
      privato: "ciao",
      confa: "ciao",
      confv: "ciao"
    });
  }, []);
 

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Accordion
          expanded={expanded === "panel1"}
          onChange={handleChange("panel1")}
        >
          <AccordionSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel1a-content"
            id="panel1a-header"
            classes={{ root: "top-accordion" }}
          >
            <Typography>
              <Icon>account_box</Icon>&nbsp;Evento in agenda
            </Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <TableContainer>
              <Table aria-label="customized table">
                <TableBody classes={{ root: "table-body" }}>
                  <TableRow classes={{ root: "table-row" }}>
                    <Field
                      component={renderTextField}
                      name="oggetto"
                      label="oggetto"
                      fullWidth
                    />
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow classes={{ root: "table-row" }}>
                    <Field
                      component={renderTextField}
                      name="tipologia"
                      label="tipologia"
                      fullWidth
                    >
                      <option value="" />
                    </Field>
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow classes={{ root: "table-row" }}>
                    <Field
                      component={renderTextField}
                      name="data"
                      label="data"
                      fullWidth
                    />
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow classes={{ root: "table-row" }}>
                    <Field
                      component={renderTextField}
                      name="inizio"
                      label="inizio"
                      fullWidth
                    />
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow classes={{ root: "table-row" }}>
                    <Field
                      component={renderTextField}
                      name="fine"
                      label="fine"
                      fullWidth
                    />
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow classes={{ root: "table-row" }}>
                    <Field
                      component={renderTextField}
                      name="luogo"
                      label="luogo"
                      fullWidth
                    />
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow classes={{ root: "table-row" }}>
                    <Field
                      component={renderTextField}
                      name="allarme"
                      label="preavviso"
                      fullWidth
                    />
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow classes={{ root: "table-row" }}>
                    <Field
                      component={renderTextField}
                      name="note"
                      label="note"
                      fullWidth
                      multiline
                    />
                  </TableRow>

                  <TableRow classes={{ root: "table-row" }}>
                    <InputForm />
                  </TableRow>
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
        
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Is there a reason why it stops working?